# latexdiff: completely ignore a macro?

Tags: latexdiff

I have defined a 'convenience macro' for figures:

```
\def\Figure#1#2#3#4#5{
\begin{figure*}[htp]
\includegraphics[scale=#4,angle=#5]{#1}
\caption{#2}
\label{#3}
\end{figure*}
}
```

When I change any component of that (label, caption, file), latexdiff marks it up as follows:

```
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \Figure{figures/param_fits/c:G0.38+0.04_0_h2coratio_minaxis.pdf}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \Figure{figures/param_fits/c:G0.38+0.04_0_h2coratio.pdf}
\DIFaddend {text}
{fig:parsonbrightness}{0.5}{0}
```

which results in this error when compiling:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   f
l.2042 {fig:parsonbrightness}{0.5}
                                  {0}
```

I've tried some configuration:

```
latexdiff --append-mboxsafecmd="Figure,RotFigureTwoAA,RotFigureThreeAA" --append-safecmd="Figure,RotFigureThreeAA,RotFigureTwoAA"
```

but this results in:

```
\DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{\mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
\Figure{figures/param_fits/c:G0.38+0.04_0_h2coratio_minaxis.pdf}
}%DIFAUXCMD
}\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{\mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
\Figure{figures/param_fits/c:G0.38+0.04_0_h2coratio.pdf}
}%DIFAUXCMD
}\DIFaddend {text}
{fig:parsonbrightness}{0.5}{0}
```

which then results in this error when building:

```
! Argument of \Figure has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.2036 }
        \DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \DIFadd{\mbox{%DIFAUXCMD
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for keeping these macros untouched or, better yet, treating the caption correctly and ignoring the filename change?

(related, but unanswered: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=24811)

Comment: I usually advise *not* to use such “convenience” macros, that tie you to a very strict format: for instance, you cannot specify a “short caption” and you are not able to do a global search in the document for the labels, because no `label` keyword appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid spaces between the different arguments of \Figure or try the --allow-spaces option.

For the secondary question ("better yet ..."):
Treating the caption correctly (i.e., do mark up changes there) is only possible if you redefine your macro such that the caption is the last argument. You can then use --append-textcmd=Figure
If you cannot redefine your macro, this cannot be done.

Comment: Good thoughts, but I cannot reasonably get rid of whitespace; my purpose in using the macro in the first place is readability.  Similarly, redefining the macros will require an excessive amount of rewriting.

Comment: @keflavich Did you try the --allow-spaces option to latexdiff, which should work even with your constraints although it can cause trouble elsewhere.

Comment: I end up with `! Argument of \Figure has an extra }.` if I don't `--allow-spaces` and `! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.` (much earlier) if I do.

Comment: I ended up having to write a macro expander: https://github.com/keflavich/APEX_CMZ_H2CO/blob/master/tex/parse_macros.py